# ms access - option button value -1 when selected

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an option button that has a control source. The button is NOT part of an option group. When the button is not selected it stores 0 (which is what I want) however, when the option button is selected it stores -1 instead of 1. I cannot seem to find the property in the menu to set the option value.

Is there a way to set the storage value when it is selected to 1 not -1?

I tried Me.Controls("optionButtonControlName").OptionValue = 1 but I got an error.

I know I could do:

```
If (optBtn.Value = -1) Then
    optBtn.Value = 1
End If
```

Each time the button is clicked but there has to be an easier way to do this that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks!

Comment: It is being set to `True` when it is assigned `-1`

Comment: Use AfterUpdate event and check if it is set to `-1`. If so then set another control to `1`.  Maybe a hidden control.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I used your suggestion of the AfterUpdate method and @XIVSolutions suggestion of getting the absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access (and in VBA in general as I recall) a true value is always -1. The option button itself (and any other control with a boolean value setting in VB/VBA) will always show this value when true.

A less verbose option might be to grab the Absolute Value of the control:

```
myValue = Abs(optBtn.Value)
```